# Tidyverse approach to selecting values from different columns in a dataframe with row-column index pairs

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tibble

In R, I have a character vector `v`, whose values are all elements of `colnames(rain)` for a dataframe `rain`. I want to use `v` to create a new vector `chosen` whose values satisfy `chosen[i] == rain[i, v[i]]` without resorting to a loop and preferably using a `tidyverse` approach.

For example, if I have:

```
library(tidyverse)
rain <- tibble(ceres = c(0, 1, 0, 1.5, 3),
               mond = c(0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0),
               els = c(1, 2, 1, 0, 1))

v <- c("els", "ceres", "els", "mond", "ceres")
```

I would want to have returned in chosen:

```
> chosen
# els ceres   els  mond ceres 
#    1     1     1     0     3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```r
rain %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  inner_join(tibble(id = seq_along(v), name = v))
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     id name  value
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 els       1
2     2 ceres     1
3     3 els       1
4     4 mond      0
5     5 ceres     3
```

Adding

```r
pull(value, name)
```

returns the named vector

```r
#>  els ceres   els  mond ceres 
#>    1     1     1     0     3
```

Comment: Might want to add a `deframe` to get the answer as a vector :)

Comment: Didn't know that one.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `map2` function from `purrr`

```
map2_dbl(set_names(v), seq_along(v), ~rain[[.y, .x]])

#>   els ceres   els  mond ceres 
#>     1     1     1     0     3
```

Comment: Another very fine answer!

Comment: I upvoted for this, but I think you should merge two answers into one. So please move your another answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
> mapply(`[`, rain[v], seq_along(v))
  els ceres   els  mond ceres
    1     1     1     0     3
```

or

```
> mapply(function(p, q) rain[[p]][q], v, seq_along(v))
  els ceres   els  mond ceres
    1     1     1     0     3
```

or

```
> setNames(as.matrix(rain)[cbind(seq_along(v), match(v, names(rain)))], v)
  els ceres   els  mond ceres
    1     1     1     0     3
```

Answer (score 1):

lots of answers already, but just to show that this is very simple with matrix indexing in base R

```
m.rain = as.matrix(rain, rownames.force =T)
m.rain[cbind(seq_along(v), v)]
```

Or, similary:

```
as.matrix(rain)[cbind(seq_along(v), match(v, names(rain)))]
```

Comment: I had tried this, but didn't realise one has to add `rownames.force = T`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), I have at least never encountered the need to index a dataframe like that. I'd suspect that you could encode your data differently, but if it's not the case you can do the indexing like this

```r
enframe(v, name = "i", value = "j") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(
    name = j, value = rain[[i, j]]
  ) %>% 
  deframe()
#>   els ceres   els  mond ceres 
#>     1     1     1     0     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It might be an XY problem. For what it's worth, the original use case is: I have two dataframes, one containing what could be considered three estimates of rainfall at a particular location and another a measure of the quality of each estimate. So I find the column name from the quality matrix corresponding to the "best" estimate (that's the vector v) and then want to extract the rainfall from the corresponding column in the rainfall dataframe.